# Convert this query to Linq to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need to find all the doctors whom have not seen a patient. I have the tables: Doctor, Patient and DrPatientXref. I have the working SQL query but I can't figure out how to make this a Linq to SQL query.

```
select distinct Doctors.FirstName, Doctors.LastName, Doctors.DoctorId
from Doctors, DrPatientXref
where Doctors.DoctorId Not in 
(
    select DrPatientXref.DoctorId
    from DrPatientXref
    where DrPatientXref.PatientId = 23)
```

This was my crack at it (it's painfully wrong):

```
var results = from d in db.Doctors
from x in db.DrPatientXrefs
    where
    (d.DoctorId == x.DoctorId && x.PatientId != patientId)
    select new { 
       d.DoctorId, d.FirstName, d.LastName
    };
    var listDrFullName = new List<DoctorFullName>();

    foreach (var dr in results) {
        DoctorFullName drFullName = new DoctorFullName();
        drFullName.FullName = dr.LastName + ", " + dr.FirstName;
        drFullName.DoctorId = dr.DoctorId;
        listDrFullName.Add(drFullName);
    }
    return listDrFullName;
```

The solution changes the variable "results". Here it is:

```
var results = db.Doctors.Except(
  (from x in db.DrPatientXrefs
    join d in db.Doctors on x.DoctorId equals d.DoctorId  
    where x.PatientId == patientId // probably not needed...
    select d)
  ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way to achieve this and other similair queries in Linq is to make use of Linq's [set based operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx) (`Except`, `Intersect`, `Union`, `Distinct`). Below is an example of putting `Except` to use within your query.

```
var drdrs = db.Doctors.Except(
  (from x in db.DrPatientXrefs
  join d in db.Doctors on d.DoctorId equals x.DoctorId
  where x.PatientId == patientId // probably not needed...
  select d)
).ToList();
```

I believe this should do the trick (untested), and simply your code in the process.

Comment: That's it. With just a little tweak, here it is:
    var results = db.Doctors.Except(
      (from x in db.DrPatientXrefs
        join d in db.Doctors on x.DoctorId equals d.DoctorId  
        where x.PatientId == patientId // probably not needed...
        select d)
      ).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var patientId = 23;

var result = db.Doctors.Where(d => !db.DrPatientXref.Any(x => x.DoctorId == d.DoctorId 
       && x.PatientId == patientId))
.Select(d => new { d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.DoctorId } ).ToList();
```

Comment: This produces: 'DrPatientXref' does not contain a definition for 'Any'. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I think I forgot to add db., it should be db.DrPatientXref. Answer edited.